# How to hide column in gridview while setting the data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have following code to hide column and edit column header. But its not going into foreach. I have tried various method by putting the foreach into DataBound, RowDataBound, RowCreated events. But not working.

```
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
GridView1.DataSource = SomeObject[];
GridView1.DataBind();

foreach (DataControlField col in GridView1.Columns)
{
    if (col.HeaderText == "FirstName") 
    {
        col.HeaderText = "First Name"; 
    }
    if (col.HeaderText == "SchoolName") 
    { 
        col.Visible = false; 
    }
}
```

Can anyone please advice me the fix. Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819831/961695

Comment: No, Don't want to use hardcoded index. as I want to make it future proof. Will break if index changed.

Comment: How about if you take that solution and add this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9716160/961695?

Answer (score 1):

Note that columnss count would be 0 when you do `AutoGenereateColumns = true`

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
}
```

to set a column invisible using the GridView's RowDataBound event.

On aspx page you can declare in gridview control like this

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" .../>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
int indexOfSchoolName = -1;
int columnIndex = -1;
foreach(TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    columnIndex ++;
    if (cell.Text == "FirstName") 
    { 
        cell.Text = "First Name"; 
    }
    if(cell.Text == "SchoolName") indexOfSchoolName = columnIndex;
} 
if(indexOfSchoolName != -1)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[indexOfSchoolName].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, cell.Text is empty string while debugging

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not remove the column from SomeObject[] or clone it and then remove the column?

Comment: don't want to loose the values

Comment: At this point, the @Dusht solution seems to be the best. It uses the correct method and clean code.

Answer (score 0):

If `SomeObject[]` is an array then you may have to try to make a copy of `SomeObject[]` to say `CopyObject[]` and manipulate this array to exclude the column that you want. Finally rebind it to your grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do something like this:

```
private int GetColumnIndexByName(GridView grid, string name)
{
    foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

GridView1.Columns[GetColumnIndexByName(GridView1, "SchoolName")].Visible = false;
```

Comment: what is the difference than my code? grid.Columns does not have anything here.

Comment: as noted by @Dusht you nee to move AutoGenereateColumns = true to after the datasource is in place.