# How to hide a column in gridview accordingly to header field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using a gridview to bind my datas. i want to hide a column from backend accordingly to the headerfield

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Incident Number
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lb_incidentnumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IncidentNumber")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

i can simply write as `gv_viewincident.Columns[3].Visible = false;`  but i want to hide the column by mentioning the headername not by giving the index..

how to do that?

Comment: maybe this link help you,this find gridview column by data field.
[How to Get cell Value by column name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715983/how-to-get-the-cell-value-by-column-name-not-by-index-in-gridview-in-asp-net

Comment: The link @minamorsali provided is great. I would suggest turning the function into an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to make it even easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
for (int i = 0; i < gv_viewincident.Columns.Count; i++)
{
if (gv_viewincident.Columns[i].HeaderText == "Incident Number")
{
gv_viewincident.Columns[i].Visible = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to make it easier to get to the column. Put this class in your App_Code folder in a file named GridViewExtensions.cs.

```
public static class GridViewExtensions
{
    public static DataControlField GetColumnByHeaderText(this DataControlFieldCollection dataControlFieldCollection , string headerText)
    {
        foreach(var column in DataControlFieldCollection)
        {
            if(column.HeaderText==headerText)
                return column;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's simply...

```
gv_viewincident.Columns.GetColumnByHeaderText("Incident Number").Visible=false;
```

Of course, this presumes you add header text to the column.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Incident Number">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that should work:

```
List<DataControlField> columns = grid.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>().ToList();

columns.Find(col => col.HeaderText == "Incident Number").Visible = false;
```