# How to get gridview row value in string without using rowindex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and binds a row with name "Total" with value.We cannot mention its position. It depends on other binding datas.I mean sometime total binds in 5th row or sometimes it binds in 6th or 7. But the field name is "Total". How to get this Total value to a string usingits row name?? or help me how to get 3rd rowvalue from grid in descending order? I mean from last..

```
I tried like this,

string c = dgvrows.Cells("Total").value.toString();
```

Comment: Provide us with the code you have tried.

Comment: A row has no name, your question is unclear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715983/how-to-get-the-cell-value-by-column-name-not-by-index-in-gridview-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the columnIndex for Total and then use that to get the value from the right cell for each row. To get the columnIndex you can do:

```
    int columnIndex = -1;

    foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            columnIndex = grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that "Total" will always be the last row, could you not just get the last row of the grid or DataSource as a solution?

Comment: it never comes in last